# Encontrar todas as ocorrências de um padrão em uma String

Tags: java, regex

Necessito usar expressões regulares para encontrar padrões em um texto. Seria melhor para mim caso existisse um método igual ao `search()` do Python, que retorna um vetor com todas as ocorrências desse padrão. Existe algum método parecido em Java?

Comment: [O `search` do Python não faz isso que você está pedindo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search). Você quis dizer `findAll`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [classe `Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) serve exatamente para isso, ela representa uma regex. A [classe auxiliar `Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) é usada para controlar a busca.

Para pesquisar por uma expressão regular no meio de um texto:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class TesteRegex {

    private static final Pattern ABC = Pattern.compile("A+B+C+");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String texto = "123 456 7890 ABx AAACCC AABBCC hjkhkk ABBBBCCC djsdhj ABC kdjk.";
        Matcher m = ABC.matcher(texto);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Achou nas posições " + m.start() + "-" + m.end() + ": "
                    + texto.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
        }
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
Achou nas posições 24-30: AABBCC
Achou nas posições 38-46: ABBBBCCC
Achou nas posições 54-57: ABC
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/CGQ3qq)