# Expressão regular para encontrar números no meio de palavras

Tags: java, string, regex

Atualmente ando desenvolvendo um projeto da qual estou utilizando expressões regulares para encontrar determinados padrões, no entanto existe um `String` específica e preciso extrair dois números desta, a expressão é assim:

```
Agência: 0000 Conta: 00000-0
```

Necessito extrair os números no meio dessas `Strings`, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você pode substituir tudo que não é digito por nada. .replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

Comment: @arllondias ai ele vai misturar o numero da agencia e da conta em um só. O ideal seria agrupar os dois numeros e ignorar o resto.

Comment: O único problema é que todo o resto do documento está salvo em uma lista de Strings, sendo cada String uma linha, e entre essas existem outros valores que não são dígitos também, por isso não substitui-los por nada.

Comment: A ordem é sempre agência e conta ou pode varia?

Comment: Pode variar amigo, apenas quero extrair os números, independente da ordem deles onde vou armazena-los.

Comment: @MatheusGrossi Quando você diz que varia, ele varia como exatamente? A conta pode vir antes da agência? Pode vir só um deles? Pode vir mais do que uma conta e uma agência? Eles podem estar separados em partes distantes do documento?

Comment: A ordem dos dados apenas, um pode vir antes do outro e vice-versa.

Comment: pq n faz só `(\d+)` e depois casa o `length` dos resultados p saber qual resultado é qual? tipo [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/H1Tivg/1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A expressão regular é:

```
(?:Agência: [0-9]{4} Conta: [0-9]{5}-[0-9X])|(?:Conta: [0-9]{5}-[0-9X] Agência: [0-9]{4})
```

Me baseando [**nessa outra resposta minha**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277411/132):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class TesteRegex {

    private static final Pattern AGENCIA_CONTA = Pattern.compile(
            "(?:Agência: [0-9]{4} Conta: [0-9]{5}-[0-9X])|" +
            "(?:Conta: [0-9]{5}-[0-9X] Agência: [0-9]{4})");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String texto = ""
                + "Banana abacaxi pêra Agência: 5720 Conta: 43821-X abacate "
                + "melancia Agência: 3481 Conta: 53895-0. verde azul "
                + "amarelo Agência: 6666 Conta: 66667-NÃO É ESSA "
                + "Agência: 9123 Conta: 44578-2 "
                + "laranja Conta: 43210-7 Agência: 6589 verde "
                + "rosa lilás Conta: 77777-7 Não vai dar Agência: 4444";

        Matcher m = AGENCIA_CONTA.matcher(texto);
        while (m.find()) {
            String achou = texto.substring(m.start(), m.end());
            System.out.println("Achou nas posições " + m.start() + "-" + m.end() + ": "
                    + achou);
            String agencia, conta;
            if (achou.startsWith("Agência:")) {
                agencia = achou.substring(9, 13);
                conta = achou.substring(21, 28);
            } else {
                agencia = achou.substring(24, 28);
                conta = achou.substring(7, 14);
            }
            System.out.println("Os valores encontrados são: " + agencia + " e " + conta + ".");
        }
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
Achou nas posições 20-48: Agência: 5720 Conta: 43821-X
Os valores encontrados são: 5720 e 43821-X.
Achou nas posições 66-94: Agência: 3481 Conta: 53895-0
Os valores encontrados são: 3481 e 53895-0.
Achou nas posições 153-181: Agência: 9123 Conta: 44578-2
Os valores encontrados são: 9123 e 44578-2.
Achou nas posições 190-218: Conta: 43210-7 Agência: 6589
Os valores encontrados são: 6589 e 43210-7.
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/uN4gNc)

Explicação da regex, começando pela estrutura geral:

- `(?: ... :)` - Grupo sem captura.
- `aaa|bbb` - Escolha entre `aaa` e `bbb`. Ele dá *match* no primeiro deles que encontrar.
- `(?: ... :)|(?: ... :)` - Escolha entre dois grupos sem captura.
- `Agência: [0-9]{4} Conta: [0-9]{5}-[0-9X]` - Primeiro grupo.
- `Conta: [0-9]{5}-[0-9X] Agência: [0-9]{4}` - Segundo grupo.

Explicação dos códigos nos grupos:

- `[0-9]{4}` - Quatro ocorrências de dígitos entre 0 e 9. Esse é o número da agência.
- `[0-9]{5}` - Cinco ocorrências de dígitos entre 0 e 9. Isso é parte do número da conta.
- `-` - O hífen. Isso é parte do número da conta.
- `[0-9X]` - Um dígito de 0 a 9 ou um X. Isso é parte do número da conta.

O resto (inclusive os espaços) é texto explícito que só é reconhecido exatamente da forma como está.

Assim sendo, a regex procura por agência antes de conta ou conta antes de agência, aceitando ambas as formas. Com o `if` eu identifico qual é a forma encontrada e retiro utilizando `substring` os dígitos da agência e da conta.

Quando há algum outro texto no meio da agência e da conta ou quando o número que segue-se está incompleto, não será reconhecido.

Comment: AP acabou de confirmar que varia a posição da agência e da conta. Apesar de achar estranho, ele falou exatamente isso

Comment: Achei estranho escapar o hífen, ele não tem entendimento especial fora de listas e listas negadas

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Escapar o hífen realmente era desnecessário, já tirei. Quanto a posição que varia, vou pensar em algo.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado E agora, o que você acha?

Comment: ficou muito bom!

Comment: Muito show a resposta!

Comment: Resposta bem completa. ✓.

Comment: Testei com https://regex101.com/ e funcionou perfeitamente, com o Sublime Text 3 também funcionou perfect, parabéns!

Answer (score -2):

Com essa regex, você pode recuperar esses valores através da propriedade Groups.

```
\p{L}+:\s*(?<Agencia>\d{4})\s*\p{L}+\:\s*(?<Conta>\d{5}\-\d+)
```

Comment: Como tem a tag java, seria interessante e recomendado mostrar a aplicação disso com java.

Comment: Nào me leve a mal mas o cara vem pedir ajuda aqui e você manda ele ler outro link pra ter ajuda? Isso não é nada legal e não contribui para a independência e qualidade do site. Pense nisso...

Comment: Eu não entendo nada de  java, mas eu sei regex, e essa ai, atende perfeitamente o que ele quer, tentei ajudar apenas.

Comment: Mas java, assim como outras linguagens, tem caracteristicas quanto ao modo de se utilizar regex e a pergunta tem a tag java. Logo sua resposta está incompleta, basta olhar as demais respostas.